# couchdb -- query through time (revisions)

Tags: couchdb

I have a couchdb database which stores articles.

I forgot storing the creation date of my articles, eg: no `created_at` but only an `updated_at`

I'd like to retrieve the oldest article, I mean the first which was **created**.

Since articles have revisions, I guess I can query `updated_at` for each 1st revision of all my articles and thus deduce when the first article was created?

Is is possible making a such query with couchdb ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, CouchDB revisions are not the same revisions as in version control systems. The `_rev` field is a [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) token which helps to resolve write conflicts and reach [eventual consistency](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/consistency.html). It is a fact that CouchDB stores previous document revisions, but they can't be accessed via views or by other design functions, they will also be removed on next database compaction and their number is limited by [/db/_revs_limit](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_database_API#Accessing_Database-specific_options) option.

You can try to recover previous values of `updated_at` field and set up oldest one as `created_at` field. It could be simply done with [couchdb-python](http://code.google.com/p/couchdb-python):

```python
import couchdb
server = couchdb.Server()
db = server['my_db']
for idx in db:
    doc = db[idx]
    for olddoc in db.revisions(idx):
        # skips all revisions, we interested in last one as oldest
        pass
    doc['created_at'] = olddoc['updated_at']
    db.save(doc)
```